# Spring MVC AbstractMethodError error

Tags: spring-mvc

First of all I am so sorry for such a generic error. The reason it is so generic is because I am trying to make a springMVC example I found on the internet work. An example which I do not know much about yet.

For anyone who is really generous and wants to understand more the example is explained here at http://spring.io/blog/2012/01/30/spring-framework-birt. And I downloaded the maven project from https://github.com/joshlong/spring-birt.

The actions are defined in the JSP...

```
<c:url value="/images/fez-diagram.jpg" var="fez"/> <c:url
value="/TopNPercent" var="topNPercent"/> <c:url value="/SampleSpring"
var="sampleSpring"/> <c:url value="/masterReport" var="master"/>
<c:url value="/DashBoard" var="dashboard"/> <c:url value="/SubReports"
var="subReports"/>
```

But when I click on one of my links. For example /TopNPercent. I get the following error...

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.renderMergedOutputModel(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:949)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

root cause

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.renderMergedOutputModel(Ljava/util/Map;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse;)V
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1157)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:927)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:71
```

7)

Can anyone please help me with this. I am wondering if it is an error relating to my version of tomcat apache-tomcat-6.0.36. Maybe the code is incompatible with my version?

thanks for your help

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per javadocs "This is thrown when an application tries to call an abstract method. Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled"

Which suggests something is wrong with your deployed application, Try a rebuild/redeploy, clean up your tomcat etc.

Comment: Thanks. It's complaining about the spring mvc classes. Perhaps I have the wrong spring mvc Libs for that version of tomcat?